# Missing c++ headers under alpine clang

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, clang

I'm trying to build a small alpine-based docker container to build c++ app using clang++. `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```bash
FROM alpine:3.10
RUN apk add --no-cache clang
```

But when I'm trying to compile a hello world I'm getting the following error:

```bash
$ printf '#include <iostream>\nint main(){std::cout<<"Hello"<<std::endl;}' > test.cxx
$ clang++ test.cxx -o test
test.cxx:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

However, if I'll add a `g++` package to this container, this example compiles and works as expected.

It seems that `g++` package contains all the c++ headers:

```bash
apk info --who-owns /usr/include/c++/9.2.0/iostream 
/usr/include/c++/9.2.0/iostream is owned by g++-9.2.0-r3
```

Is there any way to install c++ headers without installing g++? I'd like to keep my docker image small, and g++ with its dependencies is quite heavy.

Comment: clang++ should also come with the necessary headers to compile c++. But see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22522933/where-are-clang-c11-header-files

Comment: @planetmaker I've seen mentions of `libc++` package, but there's no such in alpine repo, and `clang` installs `libstdc++` as it's dependency

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, g++ is the only package providing `iostream` and the standard C++ headers. You can confirm this by searching the Alpine Linux package index by contents:

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=iostream&path=&name=&branch=v3.10&arch=x86_64

However, for keeping your image small, you could install the `g++` package and just remove all g++ executables from your final image, either by using a two-stage docker build or by sqashing the image after built, as described in: [Lightweight GCC for Alpine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54131066/lightweight-gcc-for-alpine).

Essentially, you should keep everything under `/usr/include/c++` and `/usr/lib`.
You can delete the [gcc executable binaries](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=&path=%2Fusr%2Fbin&name=g%2B%2B&branch=v3.10&repo=main&arch=x86_64) under `/usr/bin`, as well as `cc1plus` under `/usr/libexec/gcc`.